# Strongly typed ViewData for complex object persistence

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a ASP.NET MVC system where you may click on a ajax link that will open a window (kendo window but it does not affect the situation) which a complex flow. To make this less of a nightmare to manage, I made a ViewModel (as I should) but this ViewModel is a complex object due to the complexity of the procedure.

There is anywhere from a single to 5 windows that asks various questions depending on a lot of conditions (including, but not limited to, what time you click the link, who you are, what schedule is attached to your account and, obviously, your previous answers in this flow).

The problem is that having a complex object, I cannot simply make `@Html.HiddenFor(o=>o.XXX)`. So I proceeded to find an alternative and it led me with a single option, TempData. I'm really not a fan of dynamics and object types. I'd really like to have this View Model strongly typed.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Make your object serializable and use sessions to store those, and assign that object to your model so you can get the strongly type view and persisted data too

Comment: __I cannot simply make @Html.HiddenFor(o=>o.XXX).__ Why is that? What is a problem with that?

Comment: @Ramunas I suppose I could do it, I dont think there is any technical limitations, but there must be a better approach... The logic behind the hidden field would be a terrible mess.

Comment: @KD I don't see how Sessions are any cleaner or better than TempData. In fact, TempData is kinda like a short term Session that last only for the next request.

Comment: aah, when you mentioned that you could have one to 5 windows, i thought it would be a wizard, hence i suggested a session. anyways all the best :)

Comment: @KD Session WOULD do the trick, but I rather keep it a TempData to avoid keeping useless data in sessions for a day. But either way, it doesn't acheive my original goal : Strongly Typed. Thanks for the suggestion however!

Comment: I don't get your point then. Is it hidden field that bothers you? You will get your data back from it as long as you use `@Html.HiddenFor()` (or provide correct id/name attributes for input fields to be precise). And you will get your data validation as opposed to TempData

Comment: Because I feel like having a dozen loops to generate hidden inputs for complex objects would become a mess... Don't you think? There is about 3-4 levels of nested properties in those objects and List of objects. And before you ask, yes I want to keep all those because I'm not saving the opperation until the form flow is completed. It will also become hell to manage when refactoring (which happens once a week so far since we are at early developpement stage and new ideas keeps comming up, screwing the original concept).

Comment: Now I see. I was working on a project with same situation. What I did was I tried to flatten view-model as much as I could (without loosing common sense of course) but I stayed on ViewModel and @Html.XXXFor() path what gave me validation (was quite a breeze with FluentValidation). It would be interesting to see if anyone has a better solution. Constantly changing requirements is not a dev's dream - hang in there :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a case where using `Session` or `TempData` might make sense. Contrary to popular belief, you can make these somewhat strongly-typed. Not like a viewmodel, but you can avoid keychain messes by using extension methods.

For example, instead of doing something like this:

```
TempData["NestedVariable1"] = someObject;
...
var someObject = TempData["NestedVariable1"] as CustomType;
```

You can write extension methods to store these variables, and encapsulate the keys and casting in the extension methods.

```
public static class ComplexFlowExtensions
{
    private static string Nv1Key = "temp_data_key";

    public static void NestedVariable1(this TempData tempData, CustomType value)
    {
        // write the value to temp data
        tempData[Nv1Key] = value;
    }

    public static CustomType NestedVariable1(this TempData tempData)
    {
        // read the value from temp data
        return tempData[Nv1Key] as CustomType;
    }
}
```

You can then read / write these values from either controllers or views like this:

```
TempData.NestedVariable1(someObject);
...
var someObject = TempData.NestedVariable1();
```

You could use the same pattern with `Session` as well. And instead of saving each individual scalar value in a separate variable, you should be able to store an entire nested object graph in the variable. Either that, or serialize it to JSON and store that, then deserialize when you get it back out. Either way, I think this beats a ton of hidden fields written out to your view's form.

Comment: This is pretty much what I'm currently doing, minus the extension. I'm just casting the TempData["Name"] to the ViewModel at the begining of the action, and putting the new processed (or identical) ViewModel back to the TempData. I was hoping for something more transparent.

Comment: OK. Would you prefer I delete my answer?

Comment: Nah, let it be. Never hurts to have more information on the table :)